# connecting device VGA output to HDMI or USB input on TV

Tags: usb, hdmi, vga

I have been running a CCTV monitoring station through my main TV for several years using VGA to VGA which worked well. Got a mega bargain on LCD/LED large screen TV which replaced it but found it didn't have a VGA socket! How stupid! It has HDMI and USB and SCART only. The CCTV has only VGA and USB. 
I looked into the VGA and HDMI adapters and realize they are useless for this.
There is no SCART on the CCTV.
Am I likely to get a result with USB to USB or with VGA to USB? If so which?

I have the same problem with my laptop which I used to play BBCi and similar onto the TV through a VGA to VGA lead. Obviously this has now been scuppered also. Presumably this is not amenable to USB and my laptop predates HDMI. Any suggestions would be much apreciated.

Comment: Why would that be stupid? VGA has come, gone, died and has fossilized. Adding ancient dead interfaces just adds cost, so not including it makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

I found this on eBay [3.5mm Laptop PC VGA Audio to HDTV HDMI 1080p AV Converter Adapter Scaler NEW](http://www.ebay.com/itm/3-5mm-Laptop-PC-VGA-Audio-to-HDTV-HDMI-1080p-AV-Converter-Adapter-Scaler-NEW-/300616528647?pt=US_Video_Cables_Adapters&hash=item45fe243307), it takes VGA in and outputs HDMI.  That should do what you want.

Comment: Beware that VGA to <whatever> converters often have a restricted selection of acceptable input resolutions and scan rates.  The conversion rate can be unacceptable for full-motion video on some low-quality units.